# How to chain my methods in order to have my title turn visible by fading in?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make it so that when I hover on an image, to have the title appear with slow fade in when I mouseenter the image. So far the title appears when I mouseenter but it appears instantly without any fade in. The fadeIn() method in my code does not appear to do anything. Am I making a mistake here?

**HTML**

```
echo    "<div class='imageContainer'>"  
                .'<div class="stickyImageContainer"><h1 class="imageTitle">'.$row["name"].'</h1><a href="imageInfo.php?image='.$row["path"].'"><img class="uploadedImg" src="/uploads/'.$row["path"] .'" alt="Random image" /></a> ';

    if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
        if ($hasVoted < 1) {
            echo    "<div class='upvoteDownvoteRatingContainer'>
                    <form class='upvoteImage' method='POST' action=''>
                        <input type='hidden' name='action' value='upvote'>
                        <input type='hidden' name='id' value='".$row['id']."'>
                        <input type='hidden' name='userId' value='".$currentUser."'>
                        <input type='hidden' name='voteType' value='voteImage'>
                        <button class='upvoteImageButton' type='submit' name='upvoteImage'><img class='arrowUp' src='../images/Social Media/arrowUp.png' alt='submit'></button>
                    </form>";

            echo "<div class='ratingNumber'>";
                if ($row['upvotes'] - $row['downvotes'] <= 0) {
                    echo "<p>0</p>";
                } else {
                    echo $row['upvotes'] - $row['downvotes'];
                }

            echo "</div>";

            echo    "<form class='downvoteImage' method='POST' action=''>
                        <input type='hidden' name='action' value='downvote'>
                        <input type='hidden' name='id' value='".$row['id']."'>
                        <input type='hidden' name='userId' value='".$currentUser."'>
                        <input type='hidden' name='voteType' value='voteImage'>
                        <button class='downvoteImageButton' type='submit' name='downvoteImage'><img class='arrowDown' src='../images/Social Media/arrowDown.png' alt='submit'></button>
                    </form></div>";
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('.imageContainer').on('mouseenter', '.uploadedImg', function(){
        var image = $(this);
        var imageParent = image.closest('.stickyImageContainer');
        imageParent.append('<div class="blackDiv"></div>');
        imageParent.find('.imageTitle').css('visibility', 'visible').fadeIn();
    }).on('mouseleave', '.blackDiv', function() {
        $(this).remove();
        $('.imageTitle').css('visibility', 'hidden');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

One mistake is pretty obvious that you have tried to use default behavior of the `fadeIn()` function.

You cant try parameters to slow it down. e.g.:

`fadeIn(2000,"swing");`

OR

`fadeIn("slow","swing");`

could be options which can help you. The modified lines in your code will be:

`imageParent.find('.imageTitle').fadeIn("slow","swing"); //this to show it`

and

`$('.imageTitle').fadeOut("slow");  //This will be used to hide`

Comment: Those changes made no difference. The fadeIn is still not executing.

Comment: @Bobimaru You should take out `visibility` property while using fadeIn and fadeOut. I have modified my answer to reflect it.